# linked list state unchanged when writing to it from a function

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

i'm having trouble with a farelly simple function, i have to create a linked list with each node storing a character from a string, i made a function for that, however it doesn't seem to do anything at all

this is the function i'm talking about (variable names are in spanish, i'm sorry for that):

```
struct listaDoble crearMiADN()
{
    char miDni[] = "1234";
    struct listaDoble listado = crearLista(strlen(miDni));
    struct nodo *actual = listado.first;
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(miDni); i++)
    {
        if(miDni[i] != '\0' && miDni[i] != EOF)
        {
            actual->tuNombre[0] = miDni[i];
            actual->tuNombre[1] = '\0';
            actual = actual->next;
        }
    }
    return listado;

}
```

and this is the function `crearLista` which works but you will probably need it to understand my code:

```
struct listaDoble crearLista(int num_nodos)
{
    struct listaDoble *result = (struct listaDoble *)malloc(sizeof(struct listaDoble));
    if(num_nodos > 0)
    {
        result->first = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        result->first->prev = NULL;
        struct nodo *actual = result->first;
        struct nodo *prev = NULL;
        struct nodo *last;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_nodos; i++)
        {
            if(i + 1 != num_nodos)
            {
                actual->next = (struct nodo*)(malloc)(sizeof(struct nodo));
                actual->prev = prev;
                actual = actual->next;
                prev = actual;
            }
            else
            {
                actual->next = NULL;
                actual->prev = prev;
                last = actual;
            }
        }
        result->last = last;
        result->size = num_nodos;
    }
    else
    {
        result->first = NULL;
        result->last = NULL;
        result->size = 0;
    }
    return *result;

}
```

Requested in the comments

```
struct listaDoble
{
    struct nodo *first, *last;
    int size;
};
```

now this is how i call the `crearMiADN` thing

```
struct listaDoble dni = crearMiADN();
```

now the expected result would be something like this

```
NULL<-- [1] <-> [2] <-> [3] <-> [4] --> NULL
```

however this is what i'm getting

```
NULL<-- [] <-> [] <-> [] <-> [] --> NULL
```

i'm not very keen with pointer, my attempt to fixing it was literally trying to put a * somewhere and see if it works (spoiler alert, it doesn't)

so something like this

```
struct listaDoble dni = *crearMiADN(); //type mismatch
```

then i tried to fix the type mismatch my doing this

```
struct listaDoble crearMiADN()
    //...//
    return *listado;

}
```

which once again errors out, and now i'm pretty much stuck trying to put a * somewhere random and checking if it compiles and works

Comment: Can you please add the listaDoble struct in the question

Comment: actual = actual->next;
                prev = actual; this will not solve your issue, but you need to replace those lines or all the prev will point to themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return local variable. You should allocate that memory block and return pointers. Try again by correcting the code as follows.

```
struct listaDoble* crearMiADN()
{
    char miDni[] = "1234";
    struct listaDoble *listado = crearLista(strlen(miDni));
    ...
    return listado;

}
struct listaDoble* crearLista(int num_nodos)
{
    struct listaDoble *result = (struct listaDoble *)malloc(sizeof(struct listaDoble));
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: that does work, however i can't change the type of crearLista, that would break all the other functions i have (in fact to test it out i had to comment everything but the `crearMiADN` function else it wouldn't even compile), if possible i'd really rather use a different solution, else i'll just rewrite everything to make it work with this solution

Comment: If you need to return a new strtuct, thats the correct way. You may try to define global variable and use it instead of returning in function for this operations. And if it solves the problem, would you mark as an answer?

Comment: Would you accept the answer I mean, sorry about that.